# get latest text entry of GROUP BY statement

Tags: mysql

I have a database where I keep mail conversations

```
table "conversations"
ID    SUBJECT
1     meeting on Friday

table "conversations_mails"
ID    CONVERSATION_ID    TEXT                               CREATED_ON
1     1                  "What about a meeting on Friday?"  2012-08-05 10:00:00
2     1                  "that's a good idea!"              2012-08-10 15:00:00
```

Now, i want to display a conversation overview page, showing a truncated text version of the latest reply. eg

```
"Meeting on Friday"
That's a good ...
```

I try to achieve this via GROUP BY. But what I get is the first reply in the table ("What about a meeting on Friday"), instead of the last "That's a good Idea".

This is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT *, MAX(conversations_mails.created_on) As conversation_last_reply,
  MAX(conversations_mails.id) AS maxId
FROM conversations 
LEFT JOIN conversations_mails ON conversations_mails.conversation_id = conversations.id 
GROUP BY conversations.id 
ORDER BY conversation_last_reply DESC
```

I know how to get the highest ID via MAX(), but what about the corresponding TEXT entry?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql: Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this-

```
SELECT *, MAX(conversations_mails.created_on) As conversation_last_reply,
  MAX(conversations_mails.id) AS maxId
FROM conversations 
LEFT JOIN conversations_mails ON conversations_mails.conversation_id = conversations.id 
WHERE conversations_mails.id = (select max(conversations_mails.id) from conversations_mails where conversations_mails.conversation_id = conversations.id)
GROUP BY conversations.id 
ORDER BY conversation_last_reply DESC
```

Comment: great.. consider accepting the answer and an upvote if it worked for you.. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two options: using a subquery (as geeky_bat suggests), or adding another `JOIN` to filter out older rows. Here is how to do it with a another `JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
  cm.created_on AS conversation_last_reply,
  cm.id AS maxId, 
  cm.conversation_text
FROM conversations c
  LEFT OUTER JOIN conversations_mails cm
  ON cm.conversation_id = c.id 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN conversations_mails cm_newer
  ON cm_newer.conversation_id = c.id
  AND cm_newer.created_on > cm.created_on
WHERE cm_newer.created_on IS NULL
GROUP BY c.id 
ORDER BY cm.created_on DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5dfea/18