# query optimization - 'where not in' on self

Tags: mysql

I am trying to develop a query that will delete all but the most recently added row in a database. This is based on a Timestamp field, that is stored as a string and a User ID field that is stored as a string..

```
table.Timestamp -> text field
table.Retrieving_User -> text field
```

This is the query I have developed. We have around 50K records in this database and it runs very slowly. I hope its not because of the string to date conversion that I'm doing, because this needs to be done.

```
DELETE 
FROM `table` main
WHERE (main.Retrieving_User, STR_To_DATE( main.Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CST %Y' )) NOT IN 
    (SELECT  sub.Retrieving_User, MAX( STR_To_DATE( sub.Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CST %Y' )) 
    FROM `table` sub
    WHERE sub.Retrieving_User = 'userID'
    GROUP BY sub.Retrieving_User )
AND main.Retrieving_User = 'userID'
```

Does anyone know of a more efficient way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Are you sure you need the conversion? Comparing two dates should be faster than comparing two strings. Also, make sure you have proper indexes on those columns. You could also try a `JOIN` instead of the subquery, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11906581/825789) I wrote a few days ago.

Comment: What storage engine? InnoDB? MyISAM?

Comment: I am converting from a string to a date, not date to string. I will try adding an index on these columns...

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I'd try getting rid of the conversion to check what is more costly, converting and comparing dates, or just comparing strings.

Comment: WHERE NOT EXIST might be faster, since the first result it finds, it stops the subquery. Try a WHERE NOT EXISTS otherdate>mydate?

Comment: @Konerak I did try WHERE NOT EXIST before posting, and it was slow as well...adding indexes on those columns sped it up for running against only one ID. I'm going to try some of the suggestions below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work faster because it does not use the IN statement that might be looping again and again over an in memory table. Backup and try

```
DELETE 
FROM `table` main
WHERE STR_To_DATE( main.Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CST %Y' )<
  (SELECT  MAX( STR_To_DATE( sub.Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CST %Y' ) 
   FROM `table` sub
   WHERE sub.Retrieving_User = main.Retrieving_User )
AND main.Retrieving_User = 'userID'
```

Comment: I think this would be better if you got rid of the conversion in the outer query and just compare the strings, using `<>` instead of `<`.

Comment: @MarcusAdams wouldn't they have to be the same type to compare correctly?

Comment: @IvoTops this is by far the fastest solution that I've tried. What ran for over 30 minutes and never came back, now comes back in 10 seconds. Thank you so much!

Comment: @hacket, please take a look at my updated answer to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you're deleting many rows and the number of rows that you are keeping is a much smaller portion than those you are deleting, this trick from MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) works really well:

> If you are deleting many rows from a large table, you may exceed the
>   lock table size for an InnoDB table. To avoid this problem, or simply
>   to minimize the time that the table remains locked, the following
>   strategy (which does not use DELETE at all) might be helpful:
>
> ```
> Select the rows not to be deleted into an empty table that has the same structure as the original table:
>
> INSERT INTO t_copy SELECT * FROM t WHERE ... ;
>
> Use RENAME TABLE to atomically move the original table out of the way and rename the copy to the original name:
>
> RENAME TABLE t TO t_old, t_copy TO t;
>
> Drop the original table:
>
> DROP TABLE t_old;
> ```

Another method to improve delete time with MyISAM is to use DELETE QUICK and then OPTIMIZE TABLE afterward, also from MySQL documentation:

> If you are going to delete many rows from a table, it might be faster
>   to use DELETE QUICK followed by OPTIMIZE TABLE. This rebuilds the
>   index rather than performing many index block merge operations.

Here's [IvoTops answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178731/query-optimization-where-not-in-on-self/12178950#12178950) optimized. We simply convert the date back to a string so we don't have to do the conversion again in the outer query:

```
DELETE 
FROM `table` main
WHERE main.Timestamp <>
  (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MAX(STR_To_DATE( sub.Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CST %Y'), '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CST %Y') 
   FROM `table` sub
   WHERE sub.Retrieving_User = main.Retrieving_User )
AND main.Retrieving_User = 'userID'
```

Comment: interesting. Do you issue those commands during the same run such as "DELETE QUICK etc... OPTIMIZE TABLE", or as one right after the other has completed?

Comment: @hacket, for DELETE QUICK and OPTIMIZE TABLE, they'd be two separate queries, probably one after the other, but there is no rush on the OPTIMIZE TABLE query.

Answer (score 0):

I think your performance issue is linked to the NOT IN statement.
You'd probaly be better off with

```
DELETE `table`
FROM `table` main,
     (SELECT  sub.Retrieving_User, MAX( STR_To_DATE( sub.Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CST %Y' )) maxTime
    WHERE sub.Retrieving_User = 'userID'
    GROUP BY sub.Retrieving_User) sub
WHERE STR_To_DATE( main.Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CST %Y' ) < sub.maxTime
  AND main.Retrieving_User = 'userID';
```