# Select Query Works, Delete Doesn't?

Tags: mysql

I have developed a query to purge all but the most recently added row, based on a field -> Timestamp that is stored as text, and a User ID field.

Also involved is a changing date format, so some coalescing is involved as well.

Here is the delete query ->

```
DELETE
FROM `table` main
WHERE COALESCE(STR_To_DATE( main.Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CDT %Y' ), STR_To_DATE( main.Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CST %Y' )) <
  (SELECT  MAX(COALESCE(STR_To_DATE( sub.Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CDT %Y' ), STR_To_DATE( sub.Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CST %Y' ))) 
  FROM `table` sub
  WHERE sub.Retrieving_User = main.Retrieving_User )
```

This doesn't run, throwing this error ->

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'main WHERE COALESCE(STR_To_DATE( main.Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CDT %Y' ),' at line 2
```

I understand what this is, just not why it is occuring. If I change the query to a select ->

```
SELECT *
FROM `table` main
WHERE COALESCE(STR_To_DATE( main.Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CDT %Y' ), STR_To_DATE( main.Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CST %Y' )) <
  (SELECT  MAX(COALESCE(STR_To_DATE( sub.Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CDT %Y' ), STR_To_DATE( sub.Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CST %Y' ))) 
  FROM `table` sub
  WHERE sub.Retrieving_User = main.Retrieving_User )
```

it correctly grabs all the data I want to delete.

Please tell me I don't have to change the format of the query, because I've spent all morning on it. :(

EDIT:

I have found through research that you cannot delete from the same table you are using in your subquery. So I get to create a long workaround for this...will be updating later...

Comment: shouldn't it be delete from tablename ...do you require the `table` keyword?

Comment: OPs table name itself is table so he used `table`

Answer (score -1):

```
DELETE from `table` where COALESCE(STR_To_DATE( Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CDT %Y' ), STR_To_DATE( Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CST %Y' )) in
(
SELECT COALESCE(STR_To_DATE( main.Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CDT %Y' ), STR_To_DATE( main.Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CST %Y' ))
FROM `table` main
WHERE COALESCE(STR_To_DATE( main.Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CDT %Y' ), STR_To_DATE( main.Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CST %Y' )) <
(SELECT  MAX(COALESCE(STR_To_DATE( sub.Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CDT %Y' ), STR_To_DATE( sub.Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CST %Y' ))) 
FROM `table` sub
WHERE sub.Retrieving_User = main.Retrieving_User)
)
```

Comment: This is the first time I see a construct like this. What does it do? I would have rather expected (as mentioned by "Vikram") `DELETE FROM main WHERE ...`

Comment: In sql server we use like this.And I guess this will work in mysql

Comment: It fails miserably for me with "Incorrect syntax near '`'".  
Which quotes are you using there?

Comment: @GermannArlington those are the quotes inserted by phpMyAdmin when building a query.

Comment: using DELETE main gives me the following error - #1093 - You can't specify target table 'main' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @hacket If you use phpMyAdmin I will withdraw (I have nothing to do with PHP myself). BTW: is that right that you have a table called "table"? This is causing a lot of confusion here...

Comment: @GermannArlington no, I just replaced my actual name with 'table'. :)

Comment: @AnandPhadke this brings me back to another problem I had with performance issues -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178731/query-optimization-where-not-in-on-self

Comment: you are saying above query is running slow?

Comment: what is the size of this table?

Comment: it has around 50K rows of data